# Passing model data to view in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to read info from external database in MySQL.  I created an app inside my project and connected to the external database like this:

```
'cpu_project': {
  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',   
  'NAME': '***',                         
  'USER': '***',                        
  'PASSWORD': '***',                
  'HOST': '***',                                 
}
```

In my main `urls.py`, I added this:

```
  url(r'^cpu/', include('cpu.urls')),
```

In the `models.py` of my app, I have this:

```
def cpu():
  rows = MyModel.objects.using('mysql').all()
  return render_to_response('cpu/cpu_data.html', {'rows': rows})
```

My problem is that I don't know how to pass the data from the model to the view.

I have this in my `urls.py` from this app:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

The `view.py` has this:

```
from . models import cpu

def index(request):
  return render(request, 'cpu/cpu_data.html')
```

And my `cpu_data.html` has this:

```
{{ rows }}
```

but I see an empty page.  Any ideas about that?

I tried to pass a simple value in the model - I changed this:

```
rows = MyModel.objects.using('mysql').all()
```

to this:

```
rows = 1
```

Comment: That `cpu` function *is* the view. It just needs to take a `request` argument.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Roseman sorry but I don"t understand, you say in the model!!!

Comment: The point is, *why* is it in the model? It has the exact structure of a view. It *is*
 a view. Move it to the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got couple of design errors

First is with your `using()` method in the settings.py you have used `'cpu_project'` as you database name so you need to use that in order to query that database.

```
 # Use this to query your cpu_project database
rows = MyModel.objects.using('cpu_project').all()

'cpu_project': {
  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',   
  'NAME': '***',                         
  'USER': '***',                        
  'PASSWORD': '***',                
  'HOST': '***',    
  }
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database) you can find more information.

Secondly:

Like @Daniel said you need to remove the `def cpu()` function from the `models.py` not sure what is the purpose of the function over there. It needs to be in the `views.py`.

Query the database in the view function not in the models.py. (Unless it has a purpose specific to models that are dependent on it)

Comment: Thanks for the advices @Kt14, I only try to show the data in a template after connect with a external db. Now I have other error , say  global name 'MyModel' is not defined, where I have to define and like what? a model?

Comment: Put the code present in `def code() ` in  `def index() ` in the  views.py and  remove from models.py .  Get the  basics  of  Django prior, it seems like you haven't understood the  MVC concept.

Comment: I have exactly that... remove the function in models.py and include the code in the view inside index.  But say that global name 'MyModel' is not defined

Comment: Have you imported MyModel from models.py to views.py ? You are doing it wrong follow any tutorial on how to create a test app, try [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: definitly  I didn't export nothing from my models because is empty.  I don't have any function, class or method. If I take my data from other database and I don't save the data why I need write something in my models. How read the data from other database and show in a template?